# Are the applications logs stored in AWS is seqeuntial or concurrent format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

I am working on a couple of application logs on AWS. The logs contain requests and responses. Are the logs stored in a sequential format in AWS? Like request from the other account will be registered only after the response for the previous account is that the thing?

I already had a look into the logs and actually didn't find any concurrency but at a time the application may be receiving multiple requests so I am confused as to how it is sequential.

Comment: What logging are you talking about? Or, can you tell us how you turned activate the logging and where the logs are located so that we can figure out which logs you mean?

Comment: I am talking about cloud watch logs.

Comment: How is your application sending the logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs? It should be sequential.